# Unable to create Knowledge Article through Process builder

Tags: process-builder, knowledge, articles, lightning-knowledge

I was trying to create a New knowledge Article through Process builder, When a case status is set to validated.

As a part of creation We are referencing Case custom and standard fields to knowledge article custom and standard field.

I do have knowledge user permission in my user record.

But, still when I created case and set status to Validated it did not created the Article. I do checked for the required Knowledge fields and made sure they are populated on create new record process.

please advise what Iam missing here

Please find the process builder image.

[image]

[image]
Thanks,

Comment: It'd be helpful to [edit] your question to include the specifics of the Process Builder as it's difficult to help as written without guessing.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves  Please find the process builder details

Answer (score 0):

I see you've referenced Lightning Knowledge. Lightning Knowledge requires you to create groups and assign various Knowledge Action permissions to those groups. There's also an approval process involved with Lightning Knowledge Articles. Your process will need to consider these steps in the Knowledge Article Publishing Process which includes unlocking the article for publication. I'd refer you to the [Lightning Knowledge documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_lightning_set_up.htm&type=5) in Salesforce Help and [Authoring Actions in Lightning Knowledge](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_lightning_authoring.htm&type=5) in particular. Context users will also need the Manage Articles permission.

Comment: yes, before going to that step here we are trying to just create a new Article when the case status is set to validated.

Comment: @SamuelRobert It appears to me there are many requirements for a new Lightning Knowledge article your process has omitted. At a minimum, a Record type and perhaps a Data Category would be things you'd want to specify and assign ownership as well. You wouldn't be able to assign ownership to a user who doesn't have the correct permissions. These are all things that could cause your PB to fail.

Comment: Sure thanks,  I will try implementing the same provide you the result of it.

Comment: @ crmprogdev  I have tried to add Owner field and Data Category in the process builder, but I was unable to select them as it wont show in the drop down to select. And in addition there is only one record type for knowledge object. should we still need to select the Record Type ID

Comment: I was looking at the docs yesterday for a different reason. RecordType can be added later. I can't help but wonder if you've created/assigned groups and permission sets to users for creating, editing, approving and publishing Lightning knowledge articles? It sounds like something in your basic setup is missing that your process isn't mirroring or vice versa.